Single pulse when input voltage crosses 10v
When 12v is supplied to my circuit I want there to be a approximately 500ms delay followed by a 50ms positive pulse to a N channel mosfet "SI2302DDS-T1-GE3".
The 12v is coming from a molex connector of a computer power supply. As the computer exits standby I need it to "press" two power buttons.
The mosfet is connected in parallel with a momentary switch so that another device can trigger the switch signal.
When the 12v supply is turned off I want another 50ms pulse with a delay less than 250ms.
I need a faster pulse on falling voltage so devices have time to enter standby mode before wall power is disconnected.
Thinking of putting the supply through a capacitor to create a gradual rise and fall in voltage and making the trigger point 10v. This will achieve the delay I need but I still can't figure out how to get a pulse.

Welcome! What's your actual question? Please edit to make it more clear.

What is the MOSFET part number?  Or, is it n-channel or p-channel?  Do you want a positive- or negative-going pulse?  What is the power source for the pulse circuit?  This probably can be done with one IC, a quad opamp or comparator.  Edit your question to include this information, and I'll convert this comment into an answer with a schematic.

Re-reading your post - Getting to a final solution is going to take a lot of back and forth conversation, something that this site does not do well.  You should consider moving this question to site built for threads that run into the dozens of posts.

Simplified things, should be fit to answer now. Unless I'm mistaken

xy problem What are you actually trying to achieve? Why do you need these pulses?

They circumvent and emulate a momentary switch in the circuit grounding a signal

@WilliamFitzPatrick You are asking for a schmitt trigger with a set trigger voltage followed by a one-shot with a set pulse width. It may be possible to consider one of several 74xx series devices for the Schmitt and a 74121 for the one-shot. Will need a voltage divider, too, I suspect. (I've no idea about 74121 availability these days.) That's the olden days approach, anyway. Today, an MCU of course.

The transition level of a TTL input stage is not tightly controlled enough to assure triggering at a specific input voltage.

Question for William - Is is safe to assume that the triggering signal will be either above or below 10 V for longer than 50 ms?

A little microcontroller with an analog input and one GPIO pin as the output.  The rest of the problem is software.

After the 12V source is switched off, what other supply is available that shall power this proposed circuit, that produces these 50ms pulses? I mean, the first pulse can be derived from the 12V that is present, but when that 12V goes away, what's keeping the circuit alive then?

As I read your question, you need a 50ms pulse on the rising and falling edge of the 12V supply, each edge delayed by a different amount.  1) Does the 12V supply power this pulse generating circuit?(I'm assuming 'yes' for now).  2) What are worst case rise and fall times of the 12V supply? 3) The answers to 1) and 2) may require this pulse circuit to be functional for up to 300ms after it's input supply (12V) has gone.  That would require your solution to add energy storage sufficient to power the pulse circuit for that time period.  Energy storage needed will guide the optimal circuit design.

Here's one idea, using a single CD40106B hex Schmitt inverter chip, and a handful of passive parts.
There's no undervoltage lockout that prevents a pulse from being generated when the input voltage is below 10V. That's easy to add using a TLV431 or any other programmable shunt reference.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
R1-D1 starts the power-up delay by charging C1. R2-D2 starts the power-down delay by discharging C2, at a faster rate. After power-up delay has elapsed, B goes low. After power-down delay has elapsed, B goes up.
The state on B is differentiated by C2-R5..R8. The differentiated pulses are offset from the mid-supply by the current flowing through resistors R6 and R7.
Input to NOT2 is above the threshold, and goes below the threshold when the power-up delay has elapsed. Input to NOT5 is below the threshold, and goes above threshold when the power-down delay has elapsed.
The time constant C2 * (R5+R6)||(R7-R8) determines the pulse width.
Upon power up, the delay R4-C3 is used to inhibit any output pulses during initial transients. Once the INHibit signal goes low, F is allowed to swing low whenever a negative-going pulse is present on C or D.
C13 is used to provide a path to discharge D4's diode capacitance, to avoid spurious pulses when INH changes state.
D3-C14 maintain the supply for a bit after power-down, in order to generate the power-off pulse. C14 discharges through R5..R8, and through the loads on inverter outputs.
The voltages at various points in the circuit are plotted below. Scale: 1V on the plot is 14V in-circuit.

Since CiruitLab doesn't have Schmitt-trigger gate primitives, the simulation model makes those up from simpler components:

simulate this circuit

Please post larger versions of each schematic.

@AnalogKid The first schematic is the important one. The second one is only for use inside the simulator, not to look at within the question. I’ve removed as much whitespace a possible in the first schematic to make it readable. If it’s hard to read, click on the “simulate this circuit” button and a big version will open up.
